# Keep alive OpenShift gear by Pinging/Requesting

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, openshift, ping

Scenario is, I have a less traffic gear in OpenShift(V2). Due to it's less traffic, gear become idle state. I know that BRONZE plan is there, but I am not interested to upgrade my plan. So I want the gear alive without using RESTART option provided by *command-line tools* or *web-console*. I already used HTTP GET method (by browser) ,but it didn't made the gear alive . Later I found a online tool, [Is It Down Right Now](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/) and I **CHECK**ed (name of the button on that particular website) my URL. Hence my gear became alive after 2,3 CHECK procedure.

Then my question is, how can I keep alive a OpenShift gear by pinging or sending some request to my URL that is *project_name-hostname.rhcloud.com* using Python/Django.

Or simply how can I create a exact/similar tool like **Is It Down Right Now** using Python/Django ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution to my problem. Thanks @[fat fantasma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1924325/fat-fantasma) for suggesting [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

```
import requests
def makeAliveOpenshift(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    while(r.status_code==503):
        r = requests.get(url)

makeAliveOpenshift("www.google.com")
```

The above function tries to get the requested URL initially. Then it enter to *infinite while loop* by checking whether the returned status code is *503* or not. Usually 503 is returned from OpenShift gear when it's at *idle* state

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is Uptimerobot.com

Comment: May several online services there slimier to  _www.isitdownrightnow.com_ or _Uptimerobot.com_ . But, I want to do their functionality with Python/ Djano

Comment: So you want to create a separate app that pings your django app?

Comment: Yeah..and planning to run that ping process in django background

Comment: I need something like this,

    def keepAliveOpenshift(url):
      #do something to url until get positive response

Comment: Use the python requests library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131117/discussion-between-jpg-and-fat-fantasma).